# How to count and calculate only selected columns in panda dataframe as well as in dask dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have dataframe where i want to count non zero columns for each row and as well sum of selected rows in dask and pandas?

```
id     Car               Model             1.1         2.1        3.1        4.1       
1      BMW               Model1            2           5          2          0
2      Volvo             V1                0           0          10         3
3      VW                Polo              5           2          4          5
```

So i need 2 extra columns in output which will give count of non zero values and sum of selected columns

Desired Output would be like this:

```
id     Car               Model             1.1         2.1        3.1        4.1       Count    Sum
1      BMW               Model1            2           5          2          0          3       9
2      Volvo             V1                0           0          10         3          2       13
3      VW                Polo              5           2          4          5          4       16
```

I think i can use `df.fillna(0).astype(bool).sum(axis=1)` but i need to use this on only selected columns as you can see in desired output. Moreover how i can get the similar result in dask?

Comment: @jezrael can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you essentially need to do is loop over each row and apply sum aggregation function. This is what `apply` is made for.

You can simply return a Series with the desired values for each row. `sum` is obvious and `count` is essentially the same idea as you had. `s!=0` returns `True` or `False` and `sum()` only considers `True`.

```
In [83]: def custom_agg(s): 
    ...:     return pd.Series({'sum': s.sum(), 'count': (s!=0).sum()})
```

Then apply it like this:

```
In [85]: df[['sum', 'count']] = df[['1.1', '2.1', '3.1', '4.1']].apply(custom_agg, axis=1)                                                                                                                 

In [86]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[86]: 
      Car   Model  1.1  2.1  3.1  4.1  sum  count
id                                               
1     BMW  Model1    2    5    2    0    9      3
2   Volvo      V1    0    0   10    3   13      2
3      VW    Polo    5    2    4    5   16      4
```

Dask implements apply. The code should work in pandas as well as in Dask out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to define selected columns on which i need to do calculation? There are some columns where i have also integer values and i dont need to use them in aggregation.

Comment: `df[['1.1', '2.1', '3.1', '4.1']]` is already doing that. This code ignores `Car` and `Model` as well as anything else you might have. You can just add things to this list if you want to perform the calculation for more columns.

Comment: Ok i didnt noticed. Thanks. Can i select columns based on slice in aggregation? I have more than 300 hundred columns and i dont want to select by name. It would be nice if i can slice them

Comment: Yes you can. `df.loc[:,'1.1':'4.1']` works as well. If you want the details you can read them up here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

use apply function on rows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Car': ['BMW', 'Volvo'], 'Model': ['Model1', 'V1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['1.1'] = [2,0]
df['2.1'] = [5,0]
df['3.1'] = [2,10]
df['4.1'] = [0,3]
values = df.iloc[:,2:] 
df['sum'] = values.apply(np.sum, axis=1)
df['count'] = values.astype(bool).sum(axis=1)

print(df.head)
     Car   Model  1.1  2.1  3.1  4.1   sum   count
0    BMW  Model1    2    5    2    0    9      3
1  Volvo      V1    0    0   10    3   13      2
```